# Facebook Login Displaying as Text

Tags: facebook

I want to create a Facebook login for my website. I used the same code from the [Facebook reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/login/).  But the login button does displays only as the text "login with Facebook". Can anyone help?

My code is:

```
<html>
    <head>
      <title>My Facebook Login Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div id="fb-root"></div>
      <script>
        window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
          FB.init({
            appId      : '394261217260358',
            status     : true, 
            cookie     : true,
            xfbml      : true,
            oauth      : true
          });
        };
        (function(d){
           var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
           js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
           js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
           d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
         }(document));
      </script>
      login with facebook
      <fb:login-button show-faces="false" perms="publish_stream,email,user_location,offline_access" width="200" max-rows="1">login</fb:login-button>
    </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: What error messages do you get in your javascript console window?

Answer (score 0):

Put this line

```
<fb:login-button show-faces="false" perms="publish_stream,email,user_location,offline_access" width="200" max-rows="1">login</fb:login-button>
```

above `<script>` and below `<div id="fb-root"></div>` and it should work